# Is there a way to secure my geopoint while still permitting Parse.com "near" queries?

Tags: javascript, security, parse-platform, geolocation

I'm working on an application that allows users to save objects, and then view objects from other users `near` them. I store a `geopoint` on the `Parse.User` object, and have written a query that finds other users near the current user, and then objects that belong to those users:

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
innerQuery.near("location", user.get("location"));
innerQuery.notEqualTo("objectId", user.id);

var query = new Parse.Query(MyObject);
query.include(innerQuery);
query.matchesQuery("user", innerQuery);
return query.find()
```

This works great. However, I'm trying to secure user information–I don't want other users to be able to simply call `user.get("location")` and get the precise coordinates (and therefore address) of another user.

I tried setting the CLP to the `_User` table to prohibit reads and writes, but then my query fails with 403 (Forbidden).

Is there a way to secure my geopoint while still permitting `near` queries?

Comment: **Don't use relational queries with `near`.**. The inner query is limited by parse to at most 1000 users, and you cannot paginate multiple queries. Hindsight's 20/20...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner query works because the User class is by default publicly readable. The downside is that you lose the ability to protect the data you put in there as long as you have the `find` CLP on your class. The easiest solution is to move your searching query to Cloud while disabling `find` permission in your `User` class CLP to protect the data from being searched which includes in your case a user's location.

Comment: Do queries in the cloud bypass CLPs?

Comment: Yes they can, you simply put `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` in your function and then you have master key privileges which override the CLPs.

Comment: @MoNazemi exactly what I was going to say as well. Set the CLP to prohibit read/writes, move your searching capability to cloud code and utilize `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` which will bypass the CLP for that cloud function.